# Google Sheets adding a helper column in an array without needing to edit the original source

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

this code works fine

```
=arrayformula({Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:A})
```

but I want to add a column next to it

```
=arrayformula({Sheet1!A:A,"from sheet 1";Sheet2!A:A,"from sheet 2"})
```

Is there a way I can simply do this to make my query much cleaner or do I really need to create a bunch of helper columns in every sheet because I can't predict the amount of data. I'm also curious because there may be some situations where I can't edit the original data I am trying to pull this way.

for example, data output should look like this...
Two columns...

```
a sheet1
b sheet1
c sheet2
d sheet2
e sheet2
```

I know how to accomplish this with a helper column but wish there was a way I could shove it in the array formula, usually I would add it but in this case I do not know how many rows and so therefore would have to repeat "from sheet 1","from sheet 1" over and over in the formula for an undefined number of times.

My cleanest solution right now is to add this helper column

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(A:A),"","sheet1"))
```

but I want to know how "compact" I can make my formulas with the {...,...;..,...} for sanity sake but also so I can have this same behavior without having access to editing the original sheet or having to duplicate it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

you can either play with `REPT` by # of <>"" rows or use & appending with `SPLIT` like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT({Sheet1!A1:A10&"♦Sheet1";Sheet2!A1:A10&"♦Sheet2"}, "♦", 1, 0))
```

[image]

---

also in `QUERY` you are able to create fake columns like:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:B10, "select A,B,'Sheet1' label 'Sheet1'''", 0)
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the useful tips, can you explain why you need to do & instead of just a comma? I notice the comma gives an error, also when I have more than 2 columns it seems to be behaving strangely.

Comment: the reason for & is that otherwise you would get array literal/row error. if ranges would be A1:B1 then you can use comma but for range A1:B3 you will need to do it like: {A1:B3,{"Sheet1";"Sheet1";"Sheet1"}} so it would match equal amount of rows before and after comma